# React Native: compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED for

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I keep getting the error 
`compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED` on all my modules. At first I thought it was just AppSee, but it persists through all my modules.

I've tried updating the Gradle and making sure all my versions are okay for my dependencies?

Here's my app file, cut down to the important parts

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kalleonative"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

...
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase-analytics')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1') {
        force = true
    }
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.6.0"  // From node_module
    compile 'com.twilio:voice-android:2.0.0-beta14'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.4.0-beta1'
    compile project(':react-native-immediate-phone-call')
}
```

And here's the error:

````
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ContactsManager.java:26: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ContactsManager.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ActivityCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ContactsProvider.java:7: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ReactNativeContacts.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ContactsManager.java:924: error: cannot find symbol
    protected static void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class ContactsManager
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ContactsManager.java:925: error: cannot find symbol
                                                     @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class ContactsManager
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ContactsProvider.java:239: error: cannot find symbol
    @NonNull
     ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class ContactsProvider
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ReactNativeContacts.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class ReactNativeContacts
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ReactNativeContacts.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
                                                                                                   ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class ReactNativeContacts
C:\Users\Jacob\kalleo\kalleo-master\kalleo-native\node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\com\rt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ContactsManager.java:921: error: cannot find symbol
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(currentActivity, new String[]{PERMISSION_READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class ContactsManager
10 errors

> Task :react-native-contacts:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I add 'react-native-contacts' to my project. Because 'react-native-contacts' now supports AndroidX, you must:

1. Migrate your project to AndroidX. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate
2. Convert node_modules dependencies to AndroidX using Jetifier. https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier#usage-for-source-files

Try it out!